# Recreating a Message in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am retrieving data from a server via WCF (I am the client). Unfortunately, the server (which I have no control of) is sometimes returning invalid XML.

In order to fix this, I plan to add a `IClientMessageInspector` (on the client), which modifies the `Message` before WCF has chance to parse the returned XML.

My first step was to implement `IClientMessageInspector`, but have it so it leaves the response unchanged (it should effectively be a no-op), but for some reason it causes the generated WCF method (`client.getBar()` below) to return a `null` object, rather than a populated object.

```
class UTF8Policer : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Message revised = null;
        var contents = new StringBuilder();
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(contents);

        reply.WriteMessage(writer);
        writer.Flush();

        revised = Message.CreateMessage(reply.Version, reply.Headers.Action, XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(contents.ToString()));
        revised.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(reply);
        revised.Properties.CopyProperties(reply.Properties);

        reply = revised;
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, when running:

```
var client = new Foo_RPCClient();
var header = new header();

// This is what registers the inspector
client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new FooEndpointBehaviour());

var response = client.getBar(ref header, new BarRequest());
```

... `response` is null. If I comment out the inspector registration, `response` works.

My conclusion is therefore that I'm somehow invalidating the message within `AfterReceiveReply`. Can anyone advise what the correct way is to re-create the message received?

Once I've got this working, I'm hoping it'll be trivial to fixup the XML within `AfterReceiveReply`, so that it actually does something useful.

Comment: Don't use `ref` as they are useless with WCF just send instance create copy of it modify it and send back this copy or use `out` parameters

Comment: @Fabjan: I think I've caused some confusion as to where I'm implementing `IClientMessageInspector`... all my code is on the client. I've clarified my question, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref parameter wont work with WCF.

When you do the call to the service everything is pass as an input message serialized. Then the service deserialize it and do the work and finally it return a serialized  response to the client that is deserialized on the client side.

The ref parameter might compile but in no way you retain the reference to a memory pointer in the client computer. You must use the response to return back the object.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I understand your second paragraph, but am struggling with the third, in particular your last sentence. To clarify, in case there's any confusion... my `AfterReceiveReply` is being executed on the client, and I'm expecting it to modify the `Message` representing the server-response, before it is deserialized, and WCF realizes part of the XML is invalid.

Comment: Franck,  I think I've caused some confusion as to where I'm implementing `IClientMessageInspector`... all my code is on the client. I've clarified my question, if that helps.